# qt5 cmake no automoc

Tags: cmake, qt5

i don't get it
I made a small example after the qt5 cmake guide.
It is a minimal example.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(basic_qt_gui)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/qt5_5_0/5.5/gcc_64")

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Gui)

set(BASIC_QT_GUI_HEADERS mainwindow.h)
set(BASIC_QT_GUI_SOURCES main.cpp
                         mainwindow.cpp)

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(basic_qt_gui ${BASIC_QT_GUI_HEADERS} ${BASIC_QT_GUI_SOURCES})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(basic_qt_gui Qt5::Widgets)
```

after make I always get this error

```
[ 25%] Automoc for target basic_qt_gui
Generating moc_mainwindow.cpp
[ 25%] Built target basic_qt_gui_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target basic_qt_gui
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/basic_qt_gui.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/basic_qt_gui.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o
/home/gatherer/Dokumente/gitHubProjekte/basic_qt_gui/mainwindow.cpp:2:27:  fatal error: ui_mainwindow.h: No such file or directory
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic_qt_gui.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic_qt_gui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I looked around a lot but I can not find an error.
I use CMake 2.8.12 and qt5.5.0

EDIT: solution .. installed cmake 3.2.2 and added

```
  set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

this solves the problem. 2.8.12 is a really wired version

Comment: Is ui_mainwindow.h and mainwindow.h. Is this automoc-trickery or a mistake?

Comment: it right, its the way it should work ...

Comment: the guide i used ... nothing hard to understand http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html .. so its much more wired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, generation of ui_* headers from .ui files have nothing to do with moc. [Documentation for CMAKE_AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt:AUTOMOC) says that it makes CMake run moc tool for files which contain Q_OBJECT annotations or moc_* includes.

What you need, i guess, is `qt5_wrap_ui()` macro.

Comment: It isn't available in CMake 2.8.12, but later versions also have the CMAKE_AUTOUIC variable which automates processing of .ui files. If using a later CMake is possible, using this variable/target property would be a cleaner approach. Details [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html)